# How many maximum number of Desktops can be created in Windows 10

Tags: desktop, windows-10

In windows 10, there is an option to create Additional Desktops from Task View.

So my question is,

> Is there any fixed number that represents maximum possible number of Desktop
>   created..?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After asking question, I thought to try it by my self. **I started creating as many desktops as possible and here's what happened:**

My laptop allowed me to create 716 desktop effortlessly, and when I tried creating the 717th desktop, I couldn't. My Laptop allowed me to create 716 desktops and then stopped responding.

After creating that many desktops, in my Windows 10 OS the Task View was hanged. Now I'm unable to open Task View. Now, when I press Task View button in the Taskbar, it gives me Black screen and I can not see the desktops anyway.

**Conclusion:**

Windows 10 allows you to create as many desktops as possible for your system's configuration. There is no specific limit for Desktops creation.

**My Laptop config:**

4GB RAM - intel i5 processor (4200M variant) - 250 GB Samsung Evo SSD

With this config I was able to create **716 Desktops** and then the Task View hanged.

**The Problem:**

As I said, now my Task View hanged and I can not open other desktops or unable to close it. I've tried Restarting my PC but that did not close all additional desktops.

I've even tried ending the the processes of `dwm.exe` (**D**esktop**W**indow**M**anager.exe) and `explorer.exe` from task manager but even that did not solve the problem.

**Now I'm stuck by unable to open the Task View and can't close or switch the desktop.**

So sad...! :'(

Comment: this is the way to answer his own question!.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 seems to allow you to create as many desktops as you would like. I have tested this, and created somewhat like 250 desktops and still not reached a limit. Beside, you wouldn't need that much desktop anyway. If you create so many desktops, it will become a pain in the ass just to close all of it.

Comment: I've added my answer, see what I've tried and what i got..!

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the problem where you can't delete the desktops, try using the command:

<kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> : close the current desktop you are using.

> Ref: [Virtual Desktops in Windows 10](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/04/16/virtual-desktops-in-windows-10-the-power-of-windowsmultiplied/)

Comment: Quote and cite relevant information

Comment: I see a citation.  Info was not quoted directly, but rather was specified clearer.  Most important, information looks like is helpful to somebody who needs it.  Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is what is the maximum number of desktops?

Comment: @fixer1234 : True.  Poster has one reputation; probably couldn't comment.

Comment: @TOOGAM Then they should try to earn some more rep instead of post an answer. I'll include my default answer: Welcome to Super User! Unfortunately, your answer does not meet the good answer standards for which we strive. It is probably better suited as a comment. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but since I had the same question and actually found the answer...

According to [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winstation/window-station-and-desktop-creation) at Microsoft, "The number of desktops that can be created is limited by the **size of the system desktop heap**." (my emphasis)

According to [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/desktop-heap-limitation-out-of-memory) at Microsoft, the desktop heap size is configured by a key in the registry at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SubSystems" in the "Windows" value under "SharedSection".  The third value in the comma-separated list is the number of desktop heaps, the default being 768 (though as Keval demonstrated above this does not mean you will actually be able to create this many in all systems).  Note the warning at the bottom, "However, if you allocate too much memory to the desktop heap, negative performance may occur. It's why we don't recommend that you set a value that is over 20,480."

So, the answer is that it's variable and the only reason I can think of for the default to be as big as it is, is that each user that is either logged in or has a suspended session takes up at least one of these virtual desktops (and possibly more than one) and as far as I can tell there is only one desktop heap in the server.